# Does a tower of Galois extensions in $\mathbb{C}$ give an overall Galois extension?

Tags: galois-theory

If $L/K$ and $F/L$ are Galois extensions inside $\mathbb{C}$, must $F/K$ be a Galois extension?

Comment: No, this is not true.

Comment: Could you give a counter-example?

Comment: I gave an example for if $L/F$ and $F/K$ are Galois then $L/K$ need not be Galois, but that is not what you are asking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the extension $$\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$$
Then each of the intermediate steps are Galois as they are of degree two, but the total degree 4 extension $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is not Galois as some of the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the extension $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})\subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i) $.  You have that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb Q$ is not  Galois since it is not normal. Yu have to enlarge $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$  over $\mathbb Q$ in order to get Galois extension.

Comment: But the question is: If $L/K$ and $F/L$ are Galois extensions inside $\mathbb{C}$, must $F/K$ be a Galois extension? Rather than whether a Galois extension can live inside a bigger Galois extension.