# Properties of Quadratic Field Extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F\subset L\subset E $ be a tower of Field Extensions such that $F$ does not have characteristic $2$ and $[E:L]=[L:F]=2$. We know that $L=F(\sqrt{c})$ and $E=L(\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}})$ for some $a,b,c\in F$. When will $E/F$ be Galois?i.e., when can we say in terms of $a,b,c$ that $E/F$ is Galois, or, better, what can be said about the group $G(E/F)$? I think we have to use the quadratic formula here and the fact that an element $y\in A(\sqrt{x})$ is a square iff $y$ or $xy$ is a square in $A$, where $A$ is a field. Any ideas. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: I think you may mean $E=L(\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}})$

Comment: @sharding4 edited the post. thanks

Comment: @user1952009 But $[E:F]=4$, hence, $E/F$ is not a quadratic extension, isnt it?

Comment: @user1952009 see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223866/does-a-tower-of-galois-extensions-in-mathbbc-give-an-overall-galois-extensi)

Comment: Why not write the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}$ and see what are its roots ?

Comment: @user1952009 great idea. so then, $E/F$ is Galois when the quartic polynomial completes a square, isnt it?

Comment: $\pm\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}$ is a solution of $(x^2-a)^2 = b^2 c$ as well as $\pm\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}}$ so it is necessary and sufficient that $\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{c}} \in E$ which happens when $\sqrt{a^2 - b^2 c} \in L$, that's what you meant ?

Comment: @user1952009 so, thats the answer! but, what can we say about the galois group $G(E/F)$?

Comment: For the classification of quartic Galois groups see there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649466/galois-group-of-a-quartic

Comment: This is exactly Serge Lang p.231 exercise 4.